Wanted but not invoked: vidaria.services.SerieService#0 bean.getSeriesById(1L );
My unit test getSerieByIdSimplifiedTest in Spring boot with J unit 5 doesn't work, my controller and service are perfectly implemented, if I delete the verify from my test everything works fine... I don't understand the problem and how to solve it!
I get an error in serieService when I'm perfectly implementing the @MockBean for this, I hope for your help
package com.garmanaz.vidaria.controllers;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.garmanaz.vidaria.entities.Serie;
import com.garmanaz.vidaria.services.SerieService;
import com.garmanaz.vidaria.utils.JWT.JwtRequestFilter;
import com.garmanaz.vidaria.utils.JWT.JwtTokenUtil;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.boot.web.client.RestTemplateBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithMockUser;
import org.springframework.test.util.ReflectionTestUtils;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertSame;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultHandlers.print;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

@WebMvcTest(controllers = SerieController.class)
@WithMockUser(username = "john", roles = {"USER"})
public class SerieControllerTest {

@Autowired
private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Autowired
private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

@MockBean
private SerieService serieService;

@MockBean
private JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil;

@MockBean
private JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;

@Autowired
private SerieController serieController;

@MockBean
private RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder;

@BeforeEach
void setUp() {
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(serieController, "serieService", serieService);
}

@Test
void verifyMockInjection() {
    SerieService injectedService = (SerieService) ReflectionTestUtils.getField(serieController, "serieService");
    System.out.println("Injected SerieService: " + injectedService);
    assertSame(injectedService, serieService, "The injected service is not the mock");
}

@Test
void getSerieByIdSimplifiedTest() throws Exception {
    long serieId = 1L;
    Serie mockSerie = Serie.builder()
            .id(serieId)
            .title("Test Serie")
            .build();

    when(serieService.getSeriesById(serieId)).thenReturn(mockSerie);

    mockMvc.perform(get("/series/{serieId}", serieId)
                    .contentType("application/json"))
            .andDo(print())
            .andExpect(status().isOk());

    verify(serieService, times(1)).getSeriesById(1L);
}

}


Why do you use reflection to set the field? Spring should already inject your service to your controller

What is the implementation of SerieController? What does your call to getSeriesById look like?
